# What is the most valuable item(s)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft: Bedrock Edition, what is the most valuable item?
(And I don't mean strongest, I mean most valuable.)

Comment: This is highly prone to opinion-based answers. We are a fact-based Q&A site, not a discussion forum. I’m voting to close this question as such. You can edit the question to include criteria of what would count as the “most valuable” item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean non-cheat items, probably the **Ender Dragon Egg**.It can only be obtained once per world (to my knowledge, I may be wrong).

Comment: Yes, I mean non-cheat items.